# MySQL query to many to many query

Tags: mysql, sql, many-to-many

I have this query which returns all the information about an article but I also want to return which categories the article is in. How would I do that?

Table/Columns overview:

- articles - article_id, publicationDate, title, summary, content
- categories - category_id, title articles_to_categories - article_id, category_id
- articles_to_categories - article_id, category_id

Query:

```
SELECT *, 
       UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate 
  FROM articles 
 WHERE article_id = :id
```

I have tried a few different variations but no success.

Answer (score 2):

Try joining the other tables:

```
SELECT
     article_id,
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate,
     article.title,
     article.summary,
     article.content,
     categories.title
FROM articles
JOIN articles_to_categories USING (article_id)
JOIN categories USING (category_id)
WHERE article_id = :id
```

You may also want to use one of the following alternative approaches:

**1. GROUP_CONCAT**

```
SELECT
     article_id,
     UNIX_TIMESTAMP(publicationDate) AS publicationDate,
     article.title,
     article.summary,
     article.content,
     GROUP_CONCAT(categories.title) AS titles
FROM articles
JOIN articles_to_categories USING (article_id)
JOIN categories USING (category_id)
WHERE article_id = :id
GROUP BY article_id
```

**2. Use two queries**

Use your existing query, then also use this one:

```
SELECT title
FROM categories
JOIN articles_to_categories USING (category_id)
WHERE article_id = :id
```

Comment: Strange. I received error on 3rd query You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'category_id WHERE article_id = 1